# Why texturing in game engine looks different than in render mode?

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I am learning Blender, and at the moment I am trying to create very simple game. The point I am stuck at is texturing problem. I have created a simple maze and added two different materials for floors and walls. Walls are supposed to be white, and floors a bit blue with cloud texture. The look I got in render mode is:

[image]

And in game mode it is:

[image]

Why is that? Are only UV textures available in Blender game engine? I am using a procedural texture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game engine is rather limited in this regard, as it only supports [UV](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Applying_Image) and GLSL textures, along with vertex colours of course.

You can [bake](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake) your procedural textures to UV maps, but this is a time consuming process. If you don't, however, you will not see them in the Game Engine.

---

**Sources:** *Google, Wikipedia, my limited experience with the game engine ;)*

Answer (score 4):

RolandiXor's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2137/12) solves the problem at hand here so i'm just adding this as the question title is broad enough.

*In response to your [first revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/2133/2) of the question where it was unknown what the cause was (as you didn't say),* one other common problem people will run into when using textures and not having them show is starting the game engine in a mode other than *Texture*.

To fix this, simply change the viewport shading to *Texture* from the 3d view header or use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. By default the game engine will launch in whatever shading mode you have it.

[image]